# How to save Jmeter Variables to csv file

Tags: java, javascript, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

Does anyone knoe how to save specific Jmeter Variables into a csv file?
I have already tried this topic with no succes: [Write extracted data to a file using jmeter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352281/write-extracted-data-to-a-file-using-jmeter) and this code:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("result.csv",true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(${account_id});
out.close();
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147469/jmeter-not-saving-variables-into-csv-or-xml-files)?

Comment: Yes, and the error is : jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method: eval In file: inline evaluation of: ``FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("resultcsv-20141003-163823.csv",true); Buffe . . . '' Encountered "( 2c92c05698458bfcf0c0148d63ba63a21e0" at line 3, column 10.

Answer (score 4):

1. Replace your `out.write(${account_id});` stanza with `out.write(vars.get("account_id"));`
2. It is better to close `fstream` instance as well to avoid open handles lack
3. If you're going to reuse this file, i.e. store > 1 variable, add a separator, i.e. new line

Final code:

```
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("result.csv",true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
out.write(vars.get("account_id"));
out.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
out.close();
fstream.close();
```

See [How to use BeanShell: JMeter's favorite built-in component](http://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) for comprehensive information on Beanshell scripting

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your BeanShellPostProcessor. It may help You.

```
String acid="${account_id}";
FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("result.csv",true);
fstream.write(acid+"\n");
fstream.close();
```