# Jmeter Find Data Ussage Per Request

Tags: jmeter

I have build a jMeter test for a mobile web application. The test works perfect and i would see how much data a request cost for the mobile data bundle of the user. Is it possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For downloaded data there are 2 ways to achieve this:

1. Approximation of downloaded data: [Summary Report](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Summary_Report) has

   > Avg. Bytes - average size of the sample response in bytes.

   You could use its value to approximate how much data is downloaded by summing up `# Samples x Avg. Bytes` over all requests.
2. If you want more precision, and estimation of both uploaded and downloaded data, you can use one of the programmable listeners ([BeanShell listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_Listener), [BSF Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BSF_Listener) or [JSR223 Listener](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Listener)) and collect this stats by yourself: they all have access to [SampleResult](http://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/samplers/SampleResult.html), which allows you to collect the size of the uploaded data (`sampleResult.getSamplerData().length()`) and the size of the downloaded data (`sampleResult.getHeadersSize() + sampleResult.getBodySize()`). You can then write this data into file ([this is an example for BeanShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26179894/how-to-save-jmeter-variables-to-csv-file))

Answer (score 0):

Add next 2 lines to *user.properties* file (it is located under /bin folder of your JMeter installation)

```
jmeter.save.saveservice.print_field_names=false
jmeter.save.saveservice.bytes=true
```

It will "tell" JMeter to store response size and also adds a header to generated .jtl file when you run your test in [command-line non-GUI mode](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui) so you could figure out which columns stands for which metric.

You'll need to restart JMeter to pick the properties up.

You'll get something like:

[image: JMeter Save Service]

So you will be able to use Excel or equivalent to sum all the "bytes" lines up and calculate the associated cost.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for more information on what else can be controller with JMeter properties and what needs to be done to apply the changes.